# Counting builds

Tags: bamboo

I have a dozen of build plans managed by a unique build agent. What I want to do, is to get the total number of triggered/scheduled builds on those plans (without counting them manually from the interface). So, question is, is there a kind of counter on the server?

**UPDATE #1:** I'm using the v2.2.1.

**UPDATE #2:** On the server interface (Administration -> System -> System Information), there are some statistics including how many builds the server performed. But, this number is reinitialized when the server goes down.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to (Administration -> Agents -> "Your Agent")

Then click on "View Recent Activity".  Then change the drop-down on the right from "Showing Last 25 Builds" or whatever it's set to, and set it to "Showing All Builds".  In the very bottom right it will say something like "Showing 1-50 of 591".  In this case 591 is the total number of builds ever run by that agent.

This works on 2.6.1, not sure about 2.2.1, it's been awhile.